# How to use multiple Select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

Lets say i want to select (total Number of Customer from Customer table), as well as (Total Sum of transaction Amount from transaction Table).

I want to list out both result in single query..

```
select Count(id) from Customer
select Sum(Amount) from Transactions
```

Please help me to to do.

Comment: could you please add some sample data in your question

Comment: i just added few more details.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? SQL Query Store is a feature of SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the two queries in subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer) AS customers,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Transactions) AS amount
FROM DUAL
```

You don't need `FROM DUAL` if you're doing this in MySQL, you may need it in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join statement to join both table and get data from each table. For join statement refer this [link](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join) or you can use

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM t1,t2
```

Comment: No, i dont wanna use JOIN, both table are not linked together, also i want to execute same query and get the output in single query

Comment: This will produce a full cross product between all the rows in the two tables, almost never desired. You should specify a joining condition to limit the results.